# THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera. error

Tags: javascript, three.js

My code is below:

[image]

This gives me the following error:

[image]

I cannot resolve this error can anyone help me out?
Does it mean that perspectivecamera is no longer an instance of three.js library?

Comment: `renderer.render(scene, camera)`

Comment: do you have an alternate for renderer.render(scene,camera) ?

Comment: Not sure what that means, your code is `renderer.render(camera, scene)` which is the wrong order, thats why the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have attached the error image that's the only code I have in index.js file and the error is as followed

Comment: You have your answer, you are sending your parameters around the wrong way to the render function, you have `renderer.render(camera, scene)`, it should be `renderer.render(scene, camera)`. @AnuragSrivastava, you should put it as an answer so it can be accepted.